# creating a partial view which changes the content of page using commands provided in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, partial-views

I am showing a modal popup when someone click login button and then they can enter their credentials, if successful they can move forward but if not an on the modal shows ...

this is working fine ...

but my concern is below submit button I have a link 'Forgot password', and I want it to be action that when user clicks it, it hides the login content and display the retrieve password content in the same and then user enters the details and can get the info he wants ...

can any one give me some code example or something ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery for example...

```
<div id="loginform">
   your form markup..
   <a href="#" id="forgot">Forgot password?</a>
</div>

<div id="forgotpassword" style="display:none">
   <form id="passwordform">
      forgot password markup....
   </form>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('#forgot').click(function () {
   $('#loginform').hide();
   $('#forgotpassword').show();
   return false;
 });
</script>
```

You can then submit the form using the jQuery $.ajax() function and replace the forgot password div with the result etc...